# How to use an engagement split for tracking specific links in a scripted email ("You can't select individual links for this email" message)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am trying to create a decision split based on whether or not the users click on a specific link in an email. As far as I understand the proper tool to do this is an *engagment split*. However, when I want to track a specific link in this email the following message appears (see the image):

*"You can't select individual links for this email"*

[image]

What could be missing?
For context, the emails are scripted and I take most of their content from other data extensions. That is, the link is not specified in the email but fetched with AMPscript from another data extension. Could this be the problem? Is there a common solution to this problem?

Comment: do you have any links that don't have personalization/ampscript in them?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the whole [Trailhead's module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/engagement-splits-in-journey-builder-using-ampscript) available for the case when you are trying to use Engagement Split with links that use AMPscript.

Long story short, you would need to create a Decision Split that would serve the purpose of the Engagement Split. This Decision Split would check the values of the contact's clicks within the separate Data Extension, which will be populated via Automation Studio by querying Data Views, and then send contacts to designated paths.