# Links with AmpScript Not Being Recognized in Journey Builder's Engagement Split Feature

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I have a link in an email that has AmpScript in the url (https://somelink.com/group=%%SegmentName%%) and another link without ampscript (https://anotherlink.com/)

The link without ampscript is recognized whereas the link using ampscript is not within the Engagement Split feature of Journey builder.

Does anyone know a work-around for this?

Comment: as in the link is not being pulled in as an option in the Engagement Split feature of Journey Builder.

Under where it says: "Select the message links to monitor."

Comment: I confirm the same behaviour. I tried to build the whole URL inside an AMPScript bloc and reference it in the href with no luck. Also tried to use aliases, still no luck. It may be a platform limitation. The only thing I can think of is using ENS (Event Notification Service) to catch the actual click, send back the info in a DE field and perform a check on that field, decision split on journey data. There must be a simpler way 

Comment: @FrançoisPerret I also tried URL Encode and it doesn't work either. Not sure if this will jog any other solutions you may have: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/urlencode.html

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/349661/how-to-use-an-engagement-split-for-tracking-specific-links-in-a-scripted-email references a trailhead module, based on decision split but fed with a query on on data views rather than using ENS as I suggested.

Comment: see summarised answer 

Answer (score 3):

Engagement Split **cannot** use URL embedding AMPScript or Personalisation vars as a decision criteria.

You have to use a Decision Split instead, based on the clicked link/s which you store.

The click information can be sourced from Event Notification Service (*ENS*) or a *Query* from Engagement Data View.

Comment: @Eric Nguyen : no direct way, i'm afraid.

Comment: @Eric Nguyen. Since the problem is solved, please consider accepting my answer (✓) or feel free to ask for further details.