# Tracking URL Clicks that Contain AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

This is my first post here, so any advice on how to best use this platform is much appreciated.

Our organization is using Marketing Cloud, and we are using URL parameters for some forms we are trying to direct people to. We include things like %%FirstName%% and %%LastName%% in the URL so that when the recipients click on the URL, they get a personalized experience.

We are using these emails with these dynamic links in a Marketing Cloud Journey, and one feature we would like to use is the "Engagement Split." However, it seems that the engagement split doesn't work well with AMPscript URL Links (see post: [Links with AmpScript Not Being Recognized in Journey Builder's Engagement Split Feature](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382667/links-with-ampscript-not-being-recognized-in-journey-builders-engagement-split)).

Has anyone found a way to use decision split or httpgetwrap as a workaround to this Journey limitation?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://sfmcify.com/docs/SFMC%20Builders/DynamicLinksInJourneyBuilder

Comment: @zuzannamj This is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link from commenter @zuzannamj gave me just what I needed to get started with our AmpScript Link Tracking issue.

LINK: https://sfmcify.com/docs/SFMC%20Builders/DynamicLinksInJourneyBuilder

A few things I figured out along the way...

1. It is easier to track clicks for emails in separate data extensions, but you need to make sure you give Journey Builder the ability to see those DEs using Data Designer.
2. If you have multiple emails with multiple clicks you want to track, create a separate DE to track each click. I used a simple query for these "CLICK TRACKING" data extensions that looked like this:

SELECT ea.Id, SubscriberKey, LinkName, EventDate
FROM _Click LEFT JOIN "DE NAME" AS ea ON ea.Id=SubscriberKey WHERE LinkName='LINK ALIAS'