# How to identify the link that was clicked in the email in the Journey builder's jouney?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, email-studio

I have multiple links in the email which I am utilizing and sending to the end users in the Journey builder. I have to track the links clicked by the contact in the journey itself. The engagement split summary has the option for Message metrics as `Link` but **how do we get the exact link that was clicked?**

I have seen that we should be doing the queries in other links, but how do we do that in the same journey that is been running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an engagement split for tracking specific links in a scripted email ("You can't select individual links for this email" message)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/349661/how-to-use-an-engagement-split-for-tracking-specific-links-in-a-scripted-email)